# ida начало функции в графе

Tags: ассемблер

Когда ida преобразует функцию в графы, то в большинстве функции начинаются примерно так:

```
var_230= byte ptr -230h
var_210= qword ptr -210h
var_1FC= dword ptr -1FCh
var_1D8= byte ptr -1D8h
var_E8= byte ptr -0E8h
var_BC= byte ptr -0BCh
var_98= byte ptr -98h
var_68= byte ptr -68h
var_38= qword ptr -38h
var_28= qword ptr -28h
var_20= qword ptr -20h
var_18= qword ptr -18h
arg_0= qword ptr  10h
arg_8= qword ptr  18h
arg_10= qword ptr  20h
arg_18= dword ptr  28h
arg_20= qword ptr  30h
mov     [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d
mov     [rsp-8+arg_10], r8
mov     [rsp-8+arg_8], rdx
mov     [rsp-8+arg_0], rcx
push    rbp
push    rdi
mov     eax, 1048h
call    j__alloca_probe
sub     rsp, rax
lea     rbp, [rsp+60h]
mov     rdi, rsp
mov     ecx, 412h
mov     eax, 0CCCCCCCCh
rep stosd
mov     rcx, [rsp+1050h+arg_8]
mov     [rbp+0FF0h+var_A8], 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
mov     rax, cs:__security_cookie
xor     rax, rbp
```

кроме того что var_число это локальные переменные, ну и arg это аргументы я понимаю, но как мне понять где из этих аргументов this ? Почему вхождение аргументов идет прям в функции, а не  перед ней? Как понять почему именно в эти регистрах находятся аргументы? И кто нибудь сможет прокомментировать по строчно что здесь происходит?

Comment: "Входждение арументов" вообще зависит от calling convention, но обычно агрументы кладутся на стек вызывающей функцией. Соотвественно аргументы положили до функции уже в стек, а обратиться по ним можно по этим адресам потому что так устроен stack frame. Про регистры: почему именно эти? Если речь идет об общих регистрах, то потому что так решил компилятор.

Comment: тогда что значит mov     [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d, зачем сначало вычитается 8 ,потом прибавляется адрес аргумента, если я опять же правильно понял

Comment: `rsp-8` - это условный базовый адрес стекового фрейма функции, от которого отсчитываются смещения аргументов и локальных переменных. `Почему вхождение аргументов идет прям в функции, а не перед ней?` - на самом деле функция начинается с команды `mov [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d`, все что выше - это объявление смещений аргументов и локальных переменных. В машинном коде этого блока фактически нет. Ну и `mov [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d` на самом деле это `mov     [rsp+20h], r9d` (т.к. `-8+arg_18 = -8 + 28h = 20h`). Если константы убрать, то в не будет понятно, к какой переменной каждое смещение в стеке относится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ассемблере 64 бита, когда вызывется функция, стек выглядит следующим образом:

```
...
parameter 5      [rsp+40]   (optional)
r9 home          [rsp+32]
r8 home          [rsp+24]
rdx home         [rsp+16]
rcx home         [rsp+8]
return address   [rsp]
```

Код:

```
mov     [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d
mov     [rsp-8+arg_10], r8
mov     [rsp-8+arg_8], rdx
mov     [rsp-8+arg_0], rcx
```

сохраняет первые 4 параметра функции (rcx, rdx, r8, r9) в `home area`. Это освобождает регистры для текущего пользования, параметры могут быть считаны из `home area`.

Почему в коде используется `[rsp-8+...]`, в данном контексте непонятно. Но адреса получаются правильные. Возможно, дальше в функции устанавливается rbp = rsp - 8 (rsp на момент вызова), и все адреса пишутся относительно rbp.

Если это не статический метод класса, то `this` в регистре `rcx`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А то то ниже можно?